# Install CAB file from FireFox or command line

Tags: windows, activex, cross-browser, cab

I have a CAB file that contains a few DLLs, and an OCX ActiveX control, an OSD describing the contents, and an INF for installing the DLLs and ActiveX control.  These are coming from a 3rd party, so I can't control anything except how they are distributed to the client.

They are being used within a Java applet, and they work cross browser, but only IE seems to support actually installing the CAB file.

The installation is being done via:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:actual-class-id-here" NAME="name"
        width="0" height="0" codebase="xxxx.cab#Version=w,x,y,z">
  <param name="useslibrary" value="xxxx">
  <param name="useslibrarycodebase" value="xxxx.cab">
  <param name="useslibraryversion" value="w,x,y,z">
</OBJECT>
```

So, I need a way to install this CAB file that will work cross browser.  Since the above will only work via IE, I need an alternative, or I need a way to install it from the command line, which would be a reasonable workaround (I could then set up an installer to take care of it).  This needs to work on XP through Vista.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

EDIT: **Installing from command line would be much preferred**, as then I could do a solution that isn't specific to IE, FireFox, or any other browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I finally tracked down a website that gave something useful:

http://www.msfn.org/board/install-inf-file-c-t104891.html

And the resulting command I will likely use:

```
rundll32.exe advpack.dll,LaunchINFSectionEx .\xxxx.inf,,C:\path\to\xxxx.cab,4
```

Which I think will do exactly what I want.  Now I just need to create a simple installer, and it should all tie together nicely!

Comment: Did this allow you to use a 3rd party ActiveX component, across browsers?